# What is an efficient "modified" goldmine problem algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, tree, time-complexity, big-o, complexity-theory

We are given an M x N map (basically a 2D array) of values (can be negative), and you gotta find the path that makes the most money.

The trick is that the "drill" that you're using is three units large.

[So to drill a hole in a certain place (blue), you gotta make sure the three above it (red) are drilled as well](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ECTi.png);

and [it's exponential up, meaning if you wanna dig a deeper hole, then you gotta dig the three above, and the three above those ones, etc](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2uO2p.png)

So far I have an inefficient, semi-brute force (kinda) algorithm that's O(n^2) so as soon as sample size goes up (for a 900 x 1200 sample for example), the algorithm can't be done (we have a 3 minutes limit).

I'm suspecting maybe dynamic programming could be a way, but I'm not sure at all how to implement that.

Let me know if anything else comes to mind.

We've worked with Python by the way.

Thank you guys in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate all the values in O(n * m) instead of O((n * m)^2).

Let's say we have input matrix A and want to calculate the result for each position resulting in matrix B.

The first row of B is just the same as A.

The second row of B we get by summing the 3 values above (or 2 on the edges).

For all the following rows (r = row, c = column):

- c not on the edge: B[r][c] = B[r - 1][c - 1] + B[r - 1][c + 1] + A[r - 1][c] - B[r - 2][c].
- c on the left edge: B[r][0] = B[r - 1][1] + A[r - 1][0]
- c on the right edge: B[r][len - 1] = B[r - 1][len - 2] + A[r - 1][len - 1]

If you color the matrix and the values you sum, you can easily see what we are doing. Basically we sum left and right neighbour above to get the value, but we miss the value in the middle and the value of the result two rows above is calculated twice, so we subtract it.